# Excel VBA how to set formula use The Last Row logic

Tags: excel, vba

Case:
I inserted a new columns name:(Date) and (Time) to column D and E.
But I can't define the last low in column D and E, because of there have no data under D and E.

What i want to do:
column C
1/8/2016 8:24:08

I want to get date 1/8/2016 to column D. and time 8:24:08 to column E.
I found some information about how to find the last row or last column.
http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba
But i still not understand how to let vba know the last row. Can please someone can help me know, how am i need to define it. Thank you.

```
LastColumn = ??
Range("D2:D" & LastColumn).Formula = "=LEFT(C2,(FIND("" "",C2,1)-1))"
```

[My excel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOW0b.png)

Comment: If there is no data, the last row in these columns is 1. You need to get the last row of another column and use that. Btw you should rename that variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as to your specific issue

since you already have a "complete" *date* in column "C" cells, you just need to use `TEXT()` function to parse it down to the wanted part, as follows:

...`.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC3,""gg/m/aaaa"")"`

...`.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC3,""hh:mm:ss"")"`

where you'd also use .`FormulaR1C1` property to adopt `R1C1` style address notation which is more useful for the current purpose letting you write `RC3` and refer to column "3" (i.e. column "C") cell in the same row of where you're writing the formula in

---

as for the `lastRow` issue

to get the last non empty cell in a given column you'd write something like:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Row '<--| get column "C" last non empty cell row
```

but please note that should the given column be empty then it'd return `1` as if cell in row 1 were not empty. so you may want to add a check like the following:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Row '<--| get column "C" last non empty cell row 
If .Cells(GetLastRow, "C") = "" Then lastRow = 0 '<--| return 0 if empty column
```

and handle the case of a return "zero" value

furthermore note that the above code implicitly assumes *currently* active `workbook` and `worksheet` reference, which can often be not safe should you (or your code) make any `worksheet`/`workbook` "jumping".

so you'd better add explicit `worksheet` (and `workbook`) references like follows:

```
lastRow = Workbooks("MyWorkbookname").Worksheets("MyWorksheetName").Cells(Workbooks("MyWorkbookname").Worksheets("MyWorksheetName").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Row '<--| get column "C" last non empty cell row 
If Workbooks("MyWorkbookname").Worksheets("MyWorksheetName").Cells(GetLastRow, "C") = "" Then lastRow = 0 '<--| return 0 if empty column
```

where you *HAVE* to qualify those `workbook`/`worksheet` references in *EVERY* range reference

now, you can take advantage of the `With` keyword to both lessen the burden of typing all that jazz and make code more readable and maintainable, as follows:

```
With Workbooks("MyWorkbookname").Worksheets("MyWorksheetName")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).row
    If .Cells(lastRow, colIndex) = "" Then lastRow = 0
End With
```

so that you can finally type your following `GetLastRow()` function:

```
Function GetLastRow(sht As Worksheet, colIndex As Long) As Long
    With sht '<--| refer to the passed worksheet
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).row '<--| get its passed column last non empty cell
        If .Cells(GetLastRow, colIndex) = "" Then GetLastRow = 0 '<--| check for empty column
    End With
End Function
```

---

getting it all together you may may come up to the following code

```
Sub main()
    With Workbooks("MyWorkbookName").Worksheets("MyData") '<--| refer to your worksheet (change "MyData" to your actual sheet name)
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| refer to its column "C" range from row 1 down to last non empty cell
            .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC3,""gg/m/aaaa"")" '<-- write date in column "C"
            .Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC3,""hh:mm:ss"")" ' <-- write hour in column "C"
            With .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
                .value = .value
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

you may then want to change it and use the `GetLastRow()` function

Comment: Thank you to let me know this solution. Many thanks.^^